# How can you set defaults for NetworkManager connections?

Tags: linux, networking, default-settings, networkmanager

Was looking to set default values for a few network connection configs like connection.permissions, etc, so that when a new connection is generated (at /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections), it'll inherit said defaults.

Looked at a handful of places for info...

- /etc/sysconfig/network/ seems irrelevant for NetworkManager and /etc/sysconfig/network/config particularly says 'NetworkManager is not using any sysconfig settings'
- man netconfig seems to have nothing
- man nmcli doesn't seem relevant
- man NetworkManager.conf has a section 'Specify default values for connections', which'd seem usable by putting a drop-in into /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/
  However, it explains that only some configs are eligible for default values and none of those ones are pertinent to the task.
- Did a web search:
  The comment at [this related post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/336151/networkmanager-default-connection-settings) says systemd-networkd can do this on ubuntu.
  But, it appears absent from a stock tumbleweed system, and would it be necessary to add another network service to accomplish this?

Might udev be instrumental/needed here?

What's the easiest way to do this?

Linux openSUSE Tumbleweed 20240111

Thanks

Comment: bump... anyone?